# One XPath query for a button name Submit and SUBMIT

Tags: selenium

In one interview I was asked this question.in QA environment the button name is 'Submit' and in other environments the same button name is showed as 'SUBMIT '. Need one Xpath query to cover both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below xpath

```
/html/body//tagname[@attribute='(translate(., 'SUBMIT', 'submit'), 'Submit')']
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use an `or`:

For text:

```
//button[contains(text(), 'Submit') or contains(text(), 'SUBMIT')]
```

For name attribute:

```
//button[contains(@name, 'Submit') or contains(@name, 'SUBMIT')]
```

I suggest also checking if you can get an easy css selector.
Css for name would be (copy both with comma included):

```
button[name=Submit], button[name=SUBMIT]
```

The last css would mean select all buttons with name Submit and all buttons with name SUBMIT.